# Plugin Creation: Overriding upload_max_size and post_max_size

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to write a plugin script that involves the user uploading a large file. To cope with this I need to alter the following settings:

- post_max_size
- upload_max_size

If I alter these in php.ini it works as intended. However, it I try the following from within my plugin code, it doesn't take affect:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '100M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '105M');
```

I don't really want to have to talk the user through editing of either php.ini or a WordPress config file. Ideally I'd be able to perform it for them from within the plugin.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First, the setting you want is `'upload_max_filesize'`, not `'upload_max_size'`. Second, both of those settings are `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, which means they can only be set with php.ini, .htaccess, or httpd.conf. For more information see the PHP documentation on [php.ini directives](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) and [their configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

I would suggest using .htaccess, personally. You might look into writing the information directly to the file from the script, just like WordPress attempts to do for rewrite rules.

### EDIT

I just realized that I told you to do it in .htaccess but didn't tell you how. To set those values in .htaccess add the following lines to the file (anywhere in the file):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 105M
```